# git push Heroku main - error: src refspec main does not match any

Tags: django, git, heroku, deployment, django-deployment

I am just trying to follow the step from heroku site. but on my console when i git push to heroku main? that doesn't work.

**Some error showing.** like below.

```
C:\Users\TORU\Desktop\Website Again\Python\django_files\hero\hero_con>git push heroku main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/secure-taiga-84539.git'
```

what i do now??

Answer (score 6):

The default branch is normally called `master`, not `main`.
So, normally `git push heroku master` works.

Your error `src refspec main does not match any` seems to indicate that the branch `main` does not exist.

Are you sure that your branch is called `main`?

Comment: I changed the branch.
then it worked and i got another error now.

Thanks for Your Answer.

Comment: For me: master doesn't work.  main doesn't work.  There were no instructions to create a branch.  How would I know what my branch is called?

Comment: @AlanBaljeu the command `git branch` shows you all the existing branches, and it also marks the currently active branch with an asterisk (`*`)

Comment: Thank you Ralf.  It says I have no branches.

Answer (score 0):

If you had already initialized your app and committed/staged the changes on your files, you probably need to run this command `heroku git:remote -a yourapp`. Here your app will be the heroku app created like `enigmatic-brook-14304` or any name the heroku gave your app after running this command `heroku create`.
From there you will be required to `git push heroku to master`. You might have to run `git branch just to be sure on which branch are you currently operating from.